# How to measure the number and response time of GET requests a backend can handle in a given time using Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, benchmarking

I'm trying to measure how fast a backend I'm running locally can deal with GET requests.

To measure this, I'm planning to use a Python script that sends requests. Ideally, I would like to send as many requests as fast as possible for a given time (say 10 seconds) and then count all the responses that returned *within that time*, but not any that arrived later. Additionally, I would like to measure the reponse time for each individual request, so the time between sending it and a response arriving.

My first attempt looks like this:

```
async def scalability_test(seconds):
    serviced = 0
    total_response_time_micro = 0
    timeout = time.time() + seconds
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        while time.time() < timeout:
            async with session.get(url=BASE_URL + str(serviced + 1)) as resp:
                time_before = datetime.datetime.now()
                dummy = await resp.json()
                print(dummy)
                response_time_micro = (datetime.datetime.now().microsecond - time_before.microsecond)
                print("This took " + str(response_time_micro) + " microseconds.")
                total_response_time_micro += response_time_micro
                serviced += 1
        print("Number of requests serviced in " + str(seconds) + " seconds: " + str(serviced) + ".")
        print("In total, the response time was " + str(total_response_time_micro) + " microseconds.")
        print("On average, responses took " + str(total_response_time_micro / serviced) + " microseconds.")
```

This gives me a realistic number of serviced requests, but I'm not sure if that's all it managed to send, or only the ones that got back in time. Additionally, the response time for each individual request seems very low, so I think I'm doing something wrong when it comes to timing it.

My issue is that running it completely asynchronously seems to make measuring the time hard (impossible?), but if I await everything, it just turns into a synchronous function.

Is what I'm asking even possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another way to increase the load would be to use a multiprocessing.Pool to ensure that you run several parallel threads of this same function.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p: # 5 is the number of threads you want to launch, prefer a number close to you actual processor number of threads
        p.map(scalability_test, [seconds_1, seconds_2, seconds_3]) # this should launch one job for each member of [second...] so in your case you can use at least one per thread
```

However, to measure time, I think you have to use callbacks not to block the thread for each call. I don't how to do it using aiohttp